# how to delete system apps from stock rom before flashing in windows

Tags: rom, stock-rom, bloatware

I want to remove apps from stock rom.

Tool that I used is "MTK extractor".

I unpacked system.img using MTK exractor tool, after unpacking I got "system " folder.

One youtube tutorial told me if I want to remove system apps, all I have to do is to delete apps from system/app folder.

I deleted browser.apk(built in browser), drive, google sheet, doc. And repacked the system folder.

I got system.img file again.

I flashed it using sp flash tool.

But now when I powered on my phone, it stuck on phone logo and its not powering on.

Please guide me how to remove system apps from stock rom, also I want to add some additional apps to stock rom like messenger. So how to add custom apps into stock rom

Comment: it's android 4 i guess? on new devices dm-verity prevents from booting (not the case for you) you can delete each app for it's own directly from twrp and always reboot to check if device is working or not. if offline modification is a requirement, mount system.img in linux